# Why can't Json.Decode handle arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

Could someone help shed light on what is going on here?

If I do this in a C# program:

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode("{\"myObjects\": [ { \"id\": 1 }, { \"id\": 2 } ] }");
int id = data.myObjects[0].id;
```

I am able to access id and it is set to 1... everything is fine up until this point.

What I don't understand is why, when I'm debugging the program, I cannot view the contents of `data`in the Locals inspector. Instead it tells me this, as if it doesn't know how to process the array.

> Error No further information on this object could be discovered

Comment: Your title and your description seem to be at odds.  Are you trying to tell us that the program works when compiled and run, but if you stop it in the debugger you can not inspect the `data` variable?

Comment: @SamAxe Yes, pretty sure that's what the question says.

Comment: `I am able to access id and it is set to 0... everything is fine up until this point.` that doesn't sound fine. Why would `id` be `0`? It isn't `0` in any of your items.

Comment: @EZI He is at runtime... he is trying to use the Visual Studio debugger to watch at it :-)

Comment: This is a Visual Studio question not a c# question.  Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm on the latest release of visual studio

Comment: Matt that's a good point but the value it's set to is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers did not work for me, but I found an alternative way to view the array contents in Visual Studio.

I have found that we can see the contents of the `DynamicJsonArray` in the Watch window (or IntelliSense), by looking inside the **Non-Public members** of the top level object. Inside that, we see the private `_values` member and inside that, we see the values. Upon opening the relevant value, we see the `Key` and `Value` members inside.

We can then proceed to open the `Value` node and then, the `Results View`, which will show the items in the array. We can then finally access the individual items in the collection

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug/limitation of Visual Studio (at least the 2013 version I use). If you put a watch on `data`, you can click on `Dynamic View` and see that it has `stuff`, but if you click on `myObject` (that is a `DynamicJsonArray`) you only get its "dynamic" part, and not its "fixed" properties (like the `Length`) and if you try to click on its `Dynamic View` you receive *No further information on this object could be discovered*... **but** if you create a watch for `data.myObject`, then you'll still have the unusable `Dynamic View`, but you can look at the "fixed" properties of the `DynamicJsonArray` (like the `Length`) and if you click on the `Result View` you can see the items of the array. See image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

'data' is declared as dynamic type and thats why you cannot mouse over and see the value. You could still see the value if you add 'data' to Watch.